# Build Error Android: Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to find answer for the below error message from the forum. I could not.

## Error:

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module soundprocessing : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

## Details

Project Structure:

Android

```
|__  app

|__  net (java library)

|__  soundprocessing (Android Library without any activity)
```

Build.gradle at the top level (Android)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

settings.gradle (at top level Android)

include ':app',':net', ':soundprocessing'
```

## Build.gradle inside app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.clinicloud.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':net')
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.1'
    compile project(':soundprocessing')
}
```

## build.gradle (inside net)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

## build.gradle (inside soundprocessing)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Settings.gradle at the top level has this code

```
include ':app',':net', ':soundprocessing'
```

************I deleted settings.gradle from soundprocessing app as one of the forum answers said there should only one settings.gradle in multi project dependency.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module soundprocessing : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Now I added my settings.gradle as well. So what could be the problem?

Comment: This usually happens when the `settings.gradle` is not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I added a library project to an app. I solved it like this...

In the **settings.gradle** (in your app, not the library) edit it to include your libraries sub-folder :

```
include ':app', ':library_project'
project(':library_project').projectDir = new File('../library_project/library')
```

in my example, observe the **/library** subfolder. As soon as I specified it, the error was fixed.

NOTE: this subfolder will depend on your library project and will likely be something different.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file "build.gradle" inside "soundprocessing":

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    // Change this section or remove
    sourceSets {
      ..........
    }
}

// Change this section or remove
dependencies {
  .......
}
```

The section "sourceSets" need only if your project has custom paths to elements: sources, AndroidManifest.xml, resources and etc.